# Parsing JSON file

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the below given json.

```
{
  "sections": [
    {
      "title": "Title android",
      "level": 1,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 1 for android."
        }
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 2 for android"
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "src": "http://image1 android.",
          "caption": "Image 1."
        },
        {
          "src": "http://image2 android",
          "caption": "Image 2."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title java",
      "level": 2,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 1 for Java."
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 2 for Java"
        }
       ],
      "images": [
        {
          "src": "http://image1 java.",
          "caption": "Image 1."
        },
        {
          "src": "http://image2 java",
          "caption": "Image 2."
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Title json",
      "level": 3,
      "content": [
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 1 for Json."
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 2 for Json"
        },
        {
          "type": "paragraph",
          "text": "This is paragraph 3 for Json"
        }
      ],
      "images": [
        {
          "src": "http://image1 Json.",
          "caption": "Image 1."
        },
        {
          "src": "http://image2 Json",
          "caption": "Image 2."
        }
      ]
    }
```

I want to output these Json as

```
Title 1 :Title android. \n
Content 1:This is paragraph 1 for android.
        This is paragraph 2 for android.
Image 1:http:// image1 android.
Image 2:http:// image2 android.

Title :Title Java.
Content:This is paragraph 1 for Java.
        This is paragraph 2 for Java.
Image 1:http:// image1 Java.
Image 2:http:// image2 Java.
```

... and so on.

What I have done so far

```
public class ParseJSON {
    public static String[] titles;
    public static String[] contents;
    public static String[] levels;

    public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "sections";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String CONTENT = "content";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";

    private JSONArray sections = null;
    private JSONArray content = null;

    private String json;

    public ParseJSON(String json) {
        this.json = json;
    }

    protected void parseJSON() {
        JSONObject jsonObject ;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            sections = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

            titles = new String[sections.length()];
            levels = new String[sections.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < sections.length(); i++) {
                titles[i] = sections.getJSONObject(i).getString(TITLE);

                JSONArray content = sections.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray(CONTENT);
                contents = new String[content.length()];
                Log.d("MainActivity",contents.toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < content.length(); j++) {

                    contents[j] += content.getJSONObject(j).getString(TEXT).toString() + "\n\n";
                    //Log.d("MainActivity",contents.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is not complete.
I want to print the json as above.
But I'm not getting the title part and paragraph part as needed.

When I parse the TEXT from content array it gives all the paragraphs combined from the json as content[0],content[1] and so on.
But I want contents with respect to titles only

I think the link part plays some role,but I don't know how.

**UPDATE**
What if I want the output as the middle one alone.ie,

```
//android title part //not needed
//The part needed is below one:
Title :Title Java.
Content:This is paragraph 1 for Java.
        This is paragraph 2 for Java.
Image 1:http:// image1 Java.
Image 2:http:// image2 Java.

//json title part //not needed
```

Comment: Strongly consider making a Java class to hold the title, content, and images together under one object rather than as separate arrays. Use an array for the object type instead.

Comment: I am surprised nobody has mentioned Gson?

Comment: @Eenvincible can you help me with a short example using gson for the same question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the json converter to pojo tool like [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), you can generate Plain Old Java Objects (POJO) that you can use to easily manipulate your json results.

From your json string, I was able to generate the following Java classes:

```
public class Content {

   @SerializedName("type")
   @Expose
   private String type;
   @SerializedName("text")
   @Expose
   private String text;

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The type
   */
   public String getType() {
      return type;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param type
   * The type
   */
   public void setType(String type) {
      this.type = type;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The text
   */
   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param text
   * The text
   */
   public void setText(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

 }
```

Then this represents the Image entity:

```
public class Image {

   @SerializedName("src")
   @Expose
   private String src;
   @SerializedName("caption")
   @Expose
   private String caption;

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The src
   */
   public String getSrc() {
      return src;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param src
   * The src
   */
   public void setSrc(String src) {
      this.src = src;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The caption
   */
   public String getCaption() {
      return caption;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param caption
   * The caption
   */
   public void setCaption(String caption) {
      this.caption = caption;
   }

}
```

This is the umbrella that contains the two objects as lists:

```
public class Section {

   @SerializedName("title")
   @Expose
   private String title;
   @SerializedName("level")
   @Expose
   private int level;
   @SerializedName("content")
   @Expose
   private List<Content> content = new ArrayList<Content>();
   @SerializedName("images")
   @Expose
   private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The title
   */
   public String getTitle() {
      return title;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param title
   * The title
   */
   public void setTitle(String title) {
      this.title = title;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The level
   */
   public int getLevel() {
      return level;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param level
   * The level
   */
   public void setLevel(int level) {
      this.level = level;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The content
   */
   public List<Content> getContent() {
      return content;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param content
   * The content
   */
   public void setContent(List<Content> content) {
      this.content = content;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @return
   * The images
   */
   public List<Image> getImages() {
      return images;
   }

   /**
   * 
   * @param images
   * The images
   */
   public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
      this.images = images;
   }

}
```

After generating them and saving in your project like any other class, you can now use `Gson` to convert your json String into these objects with properties.

Since you get a `List` of Sections in your json response, what you can do is simple:

```
List<Section> sections = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Section.class);
```

Now you have a list of sections that you can loop through to obtain images and content. Content, remember, has a list of its own, just like images do. From that you should be able to easily get your data.

I hope this helps you.

You can use Gradle to add Gson or download the jar file and add to your `/libs` folder in android studio.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you torture yourself by manually parse JSON? May I recommend you to use some lightweight JSON Parser. This is how I do that in Android with `org.codehaus.jackson` mapper:

```
package yourpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonMapper
{
    private static ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static Object fromJsonToJavaObject(String jsonObject, Class<?> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, clazz);
    }

    public static String fromJavaObjectToJson(Object javaObject) throws JsonGenerationException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        objectMapper.writeValue(stringWriter, javaObject);

        return stringWriter.toString();
    }

    public static List<?> fromJsonToJavaObjects(String jsonObject, Class<?> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
    {
        return objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clazz));
    }
}
```

For your case, just pass the JSON string and the expected result type to the first method like `TitleWithImages.class`.
This would be the Maven dependency (but you are using Android studio):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Or `new Gson().fromJson(String, Class)`... A lot shorter to accomplish the same task

Comment: @cricket_007 Some time ago, I think I had out of memory error problems on Android when using Gson and parsing a lot of data. And why is it shorter than my proposal with `objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, clazz);`?

Comment: Defining the object mapper is one more line of code :) I did use Jackson some time ago, but I'm not sure why I switched to Gson

Comment: @Bevor . Thanks for the answer. But I have no experience using Jackson or Gson. And I didn't understand the 'expected result type'. What should be there in the class?

Comment: @AlexanderTheGreat In the end to pass your result to a java object, right? So you need to define this class, let's call it `Sections` with a list of `Section` objects. These `Section` objects have attributes like `title` and `level` and a list of `Content` objects. These objects have `type` and `text` attributes. Same with `images`. All attributes must have  getters and setters.

Comment: The first sentence should be "In the end you pass your result to a java object, right?"

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        sections = jsonObject.getJSONArray("sections");
        for (int i = 0; i < sections.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject contentJSON = sections.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.d("", "Title: "+ contentJSON.getString("level") + " " + contentJSON.getString("title") );
            JSONArray contentArray = contentJSON.getJSONArray("content");
            Log.d("","Content: " + contentJSON.getString("level") + " "  );
            for (int j = 0; j < contentArray.length(); j++) {
                Log.d("",contentArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("text"));
            }
            JSONArray imageArray = contentJSON.getJSONArray("images");
            Log.d("","Images: " + contentJSON.getString("level") + " "  );
            for (int j = 0; j < imageArray.length(); j++) {
                Log.d("",imageArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("src"));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I have printed the output on Logcat you can just add it in string arrays or better create object with parameters you need

Comment: I have changed the question for a different output.
The answer you gave above is working . But then only I remembered for this particular change to be made.
Can you make the answer work for that one too.

Comment: just compare your title with which ever section you want to parse. If it matches then parse and store the rest of things.
`if (contentJSON.getString("title").equals("Title Java"))` 
then parse rest or continue the loop